BigQuery Event count strongly differ from displayed Firebase Analytics data
I have a question about sending data from Firebase to BigQuery.
we see that the count of events in Firebase is greater than in BigQuery.
for example, for the missons_start event the count of events by day in Firebase is always greater than in BigQuery.
Google Firebase Analytics Dashboard:
enter image description here
enter image description here
This is the query used to compare results:
`SELECT count(event_timestamp),event_date 
FROM idle-lostprod.analytics_457297980.events_intraday_* 
where event_name='mission_start'
group by event_date`

and this is the result I get:
enter image description here
It seems like not all data is sent to BigQuery.
At this stage, we have very little data, so the limits on the amount of sent data should not be triggered.
If it is important we use Export Streaming settings.
Do you have the same problem? Why might the data differ?
